# @import in less file being compiled twice

Tags: less, gruntjs

Here is my problem. In my css directory I have a less directory that holds page.less, and search.less. Inside page.less I am using the import method to render my search styles when grunt complies my less files. I end up with page.css. In page.css the search styles are being added twice even though inside the page.less file I am only importing it in one place

My gruntfile.js is as follows

```
  less: {
        options: {
            compress: false,
            ieCompat: false
        },
        dev: {
            dest: "css/page.css",
            src: [
                "css/less/*"
            ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, since I don't know how Grunt deals with Less imports and the default in Less already is to @import only once. But you might want to try using `@import (once) 'yourfile.less'` and see what happens.

Comment: The pattern `src: ["css/less/*"]` is compiling all files. This pattern should only include files that are not imported into other files, otherwise you will be including file `B` (which imports file `A`) and file `A` itself - again. In `compass-sass` the underscore is used to identify files being imported into others, while "main" files (which import others) have no underscore.

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée Wow can't believe i missed that thank you for the explanation. Its working now.

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée: That sounds worthy of an answer to me. You should post it as such.

Comment: @ScottS: posting my comment as an answer since it's been proven useful... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern `src: ["css/less/*"]` is compiling all files.

This pattern should only include files that are not imported into other files, otherwise you will be including file **B** (which imports file **A**) and file **A** itself - again.

In compass-sass the underscore is used to identify files being imported into others, while "main" files (which import others) have no underscore.